# What endpoints are supported by the Facebook API Read Tier

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, readonly

The Facebook best practices document says that there's a read only tier for facebook API using which can result in faster performance.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/best-practices/

It doesn't contain any link, or information as to which endpoints are supported. Apparently the 'comprehensive list' is in the PHP SDK.

I don't have the PHP SDK, and I am not developing on PHP. When I visited the PHP SDK Git, I found that the entire wiki has been deleted, and the link to the page which had the documentation (given on the wiki) doesn't say anything about the read only api endpoints.

Has anyone worked with the Facebook read only api? Can you tell me what endpoints are supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url is : https://api-read.facebook.com/

And the supported endpoints are :

```
  array('admin.getallocation' => 1,
        'admin.getappproperties' => 1,
        'admin.getbannedusers' => 1,
        'admin.getlivestreamvialink' => 1,
        'admin.getmetrics' => 1,
        'admin.getrestrictioninfo' => 1,
        'application.getpublicinfo' => 1,
        'auth.getapppublickey' => 1,
        'auth.getsession' => 1,
        'auth.getsignedpublicsessiondata' => 1,
        'comments.get' => 1,
        'connect.getunconnectedfriendscount' => 1,
        'dashboard.getactivity' => 1,
        'dashboard.getcount' => 1,
        'dashboard.getglobalnews' => 1,
        'dashboard.getnews' => 1,
        'dashboard.multigetcount' => 1,
        'dashboard.multigetnews' => 1,
        'data.getcookies' => 1,
        'events.get' => 1,
        'events.getmembers' => 1,
        'fbml.getcustomtags' => 1,
        'feed.getappfriendstories' => 1,
        'feed.getregisteredtemplatebundlebyid' => 1,
        'feed.getregisteredtemplatebundles' => 1,
        'fql.multiquery' => 1,
        'fql.query' => 1,
        'friends.arefriends' => 1,
        'friends.get' => 1,
        'friends.getappusers' => 1,
        'friends.getlists' => 1,
        'friends.getmutualfriends' => 1,
        'gifts.get' => 1,
        'groups.get' => 1,
        'groups.getmembers' => 1,
        'intl.gettranslations' => 1,
        'links.get' => 1,
        'notes.get' => 1,
        'notifications.get' => 1,
        'pages.getinfo' => 1,
        'pages.isadmin' => 1,
        'pages.isappadded' => 1,
        'pages.isfan' => 1,
        'permissions.checkavailableapiaccess' => 1,
        'permissions.checkgrantedapiaccess' => 1,
        'photos.get' => 1,
        'photos.getalbums' => 1,
        'photos.gettags' => 1,
        'profile.getinfo' => 1,
        'profile.getinfooptions' => 1,
        'stream.get' => 1,
        'stream.getcomments' => 1,
        'stream.getfilters' => 1,
        'users.getinfo' => 1,
        'users.getloggedinuser' => 1,
        'users.getstandardinfo' => 1,
        'users.hasapppermission' => 1,
        'users.isappuser' => 1,
        'users.isverified' => 1,
        'video.getuploadlimits' => 1);
```

From : https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php

Comment: *2017 Update*: It looks like the read-only tier is not documented anywhere on facebook any more. Also, the github url of the old php-sdk which supported api-read has now been moved here: https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk